# Postgresql giving me non chronological values for my (id's). It skips numbers hence giving disorganised id numbers that are bigserial data type

Tags: postgresql, postman, fastapi

I am creating a fastapi app that performs CRUD operations on a post table using row sql queries

> I have been using PostgreSQL for quite sometime now and actually created my database schema(post) well and as I was adding data from my postman client(testing the api), to save it through a fastapi post endpoint,data was being saved to the database in a chronological order to my database table called post.However, along the way, it stopped saving the data in a chronological way but started to skip values like from 1,2,3... to 1,2,3,37,38,39,40 yet this is supposed to be done in a chronological way in terms of the id whose datatype is the bigserial datatype.
> Here is my code

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, status, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
import time

app = FastAPI()  


#API schema
class Post(BaseModel):
    title:str
    content:str
    published : bool = True
    rating: Optional[int] = None


#database connection
while True:#infinite loop 
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost",database="fastapi",user="postgres",password="12345678", 
        cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print("Hoorray!!!!! Connection to database established")
        break
    except Exception as error:#Here we place code on what is to happen in case a error occurs
        print("Connection to database failed")
        print("Error", error)
        time.sleep(2)


@app.get("/")
def root():
    return {"message":  "Welcome to our first lesson on api creation, we are going to learn lots of stuff!!! So grab a cup of coffee and get rolling"}


#Get all posts endpoint
@app.get("/posts")
def get_posts():
    cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM posts""")
    posts = cursor.fetchall()
    return {"data":posts}


#Retrieve individual post
@app.get("/posts/{id}")
def get_post(id:int):
    cursor.execute(""" SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = %s """,(str(id)))#we convert the id to a string
    post = cursor.fetchone()
    if not post:
        raise HTTPException(status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail=f"post with id: {id} does not exist")
    return {"post_detail":post}



#Create posts endpoint
@app.post("/posts", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
def create_post(post: Post):
   cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO posts(title,content,published) VALUES(%s, %s, %s) RETURNING * """,
                  (post.title,post.content,post.published))
   new_post = cursor.fetchone()
   conn.commit()
   return {"data":new_post}
```

[Image of the post table in pgadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4nAP.png)

[Image of my postmain client code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9O0T.png)

There's no clear answer gotten and I expect saving to the database to take place is a chronological order in terms of the id but data is not being saved in that way making me think there's a bug with postgres

Comment: Why do you think there shouldn't be gaps? What in the manuals suggests it should work that way? Do you think that is physically possible in the face of concurrent inserts to your table? Or to put it another way, no, you're wrong - it doesn't work like that and for good reasons too

Comment: A sequence will be invoked (next value retrieved) even if a transaction is aborted, so you can't assume that the ids will be sequential (they'll not necessary be chronological either, since a sessions can reserve a set of ids (a cache) to help speed up inserts): https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266405/does-ordering-by-auto-incrementing-pk-ensure-chronological-order - if you need sequential, non-revokable  ids (i.e. they'll always be present and always chronological - such as for invoices under given jurisdiction), that will require special care and implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am going to have to learn database administration to gain more knowledge.